# Can't access certain websites

Tags: dns, firewall, network

I'm trying to access the site http://www.svenskadomaner.se but it's unreachable from my MacBook Pro (OSX 10.8.5). The domain belongs to a web hosting company and it's not only this specific site I can't reach but all sites on their servers.

What I've tried/checked:

- Different browsers
- Different connections (home, work, friends)
- Different user profiles
- Firewall (turned off)
- No AV programs (as what I can see)
- Checked /etc/hosts
- Flush DNS
- Changed to Google's DNS
- Ping svenskadomaner.se (Request timeout)
- Traceroute svenskadomaner.se (stops at first step)
- Update to Mavericks

Their IP is : 5.150.255.189

I'm really out of options here. What is the next thing to try?

**Note:** I can access the sites through a proxy site

Comment: trace route is another one. I can access the web site, but dont understand a word on it :)

Comment: What is the URL you are given i.e. the whole thing beginning with http ?

Comment: Alternatively change user on your mac, or try using a proxy server to connect. I used the https://www.svenskadomaner.se/ and got connected to the main page.

Comment: @Mark: it's normal http:// www.svenskadomaner.se

Comment: traceroute gives me: "2  * *traceroute: sendto: No route to host and traceroute: sendto: Host is down

Comment: If normal http then the port is 80 and that URL is for 80 and I get a page -  so what exactly is the ports  2083 and 2096 from? Which web hosting company did you call?  AS for ping and trace route those can be block but http works

Comment: @Mark: He just told me they use these ports so I figured it may have to do with them. But in that case you're right and the problem may not have to do with the ports.

Comment: Then I am confused as the URL is port 80 and I can't see what those ports are for.

Comment: @Mark: Ok. In that case the ports isn't the problem here and I should maybe change the question?

Comment: In cases like this, a Netalyzr output would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `hosts` file. You can find it by clicking on the "Go' menu in the Finder and select "Go to folder..." then type "/etc/hosts". Copy the file on to your Desktop and open it with Text Edit.

You'll see the following lines at the top of the file :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

If you have others lines underneath, look for the domain "svenskadomaner.se" in a line such as `127.0.0.1 svenskadomaner.se`. If you find a line like this, then your Mac redirects the domain to your localhost (your Mac) and of course it won't find the server. This is the technique to block a website on a computer. So delete the line, save the hosts file and replace the "/etc/hosts" file with the one that is on your desktop.

Then you can try again to go the website ;-)

Edit : It's possible that you don't have "127.0.0.1 svenskadomaner.se" in the file but something like "127.0.0.1 *IP Address*" where *IP Address* is the address of the servers of www.svenskadomaner.se.

Comment: If you've already check the hosts file and if you've tried with your computer on other networks in other places, so the problem is on your Mac and not on the router on any other peripheric on your network. Anyone else had an idea where the problem can be on holyredbeard's Mac ?

Comment: This is good stuff, So to block a web site ! by entering its IP in to this file?

Comment: @Tibimac: Checked the hosts file and there where some lines starting with 127.0.0.1. Even though I don't think they have anything to do with svenskadomaner.se I deleted them, saved and tried again with no luck. Do I need to restart my computer for this to have effect?

Comment: @Buscar웃 : Yes if you want to disable any access to a website, go to this file and add " 12.0.0.1 *domain name* or *ip address*".

Comment: @holyredbeard : Try to reboot your computer... maybe... But you must not delete the lines at the top of the file (lines quoted in my answer above) !

Comment: @Tibimac: Kept the stuff on the top and commented out the rest (#). Tried to reboot but it didn't work :/

Comment: @holyredbeard sorry to hear it :-/ If you have the problem with an other new user on the same Mac the problem is either in /Library/ either in /System/Libray/ but I don't know where now. sorry

Comment: @Tibimac: Ok, I'll find it out somehow. Thanks alot for your help anyway!

Comment: Thanks guys have edited my post. I'm french so my english isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally solved it!

I'm not really sure but I think the application LogMeIn was the problem. What I did was to remove some startup items in:

/Library/LaunchAgents

/Library/LaunchDaemons

I removed the plists for LogMeIn and GPGTools (I'm not using these anymore and will delete them completely) and restarted and it suddenly worked!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked:

Delete the folder: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration

Then reboot - the system will re-create the folder with default parameters, and this will likely solve your problem too.